# How to create upper triangular matrix in Pytorch?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

Simple question, but is there a native way to create an upper triangular matrix from an existing matrix in Pytorch? I was thinking of using a mask, but even that requires creating the upper triangular matrix.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but have you looked at [`torch.triu()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.triu)

Comment: Thanks! It seems like they actually ported over all the np functionality :)

Answer (score 4):

```py
import torch
upper_tri = torch.ones(rol, col).triu()
```

Eg:

```
>> mat = torch.ones(3, 3).triu()
>> print(mat)
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import torch

l = torch.tril(torch.ones(row, column))
```

This will return the lower triangular part of the matrix of size `(row, column)`.